# Как конвертировать id в viewkey?

Tags: php

Имеется ссылка видео `https://cv.phncdn.com/videos/201702/14/106201472/720P_1500K_106201472.mp4?a5dcae8e...`
я из нее беру `id` видео на pornhub `106201472`, с помощью этого id надо получить ссылку на страницу с видео, вида:

```
pornhub.com/view_video.php?viewkey=ph59b5c9dded69b
```

может кто знает, есть там возможность по id открыть видео, если нет viewkey

Comment: Слушай, можешь поделиться своим методом авторизации(или как ты по другому извлекаешь ссылки на скачивание видео)?Я пытался сам сделать через curl, но что-то не выходит.
Извини что не комментом - баллов не хватает.Так же есть скрипт для извлечения ссылок на страницы с видео, скорее всего то, что тебе надо.Буду рад за помощь, т.к. сам голову ломаю уже не первую неделю с этой авторизацией :C

Comment: @Mastas вот так

    $res = file_get_contents('https://www.pornhub.com/view_video.php?viewkey=IDVIEO');
    preg_match('#"quality":"720","videoUrl":"(.*)"#Usi', $res, $get_url);
    print_r($get_url); exit;